# Static folder has items in it, but opening the website with devtools on chrome, nothing is in the static folder/CSS sheet

Tags: python, css, flask, static, uwsgi

I have a website hosted on an EC2 server with Flask and uwsgi, and I run it with docker. The problem is that the CSS file that I see in DevTools is empty(css file empty in the website, but the file has code when i check it on my computer), but when I open the CSS file on my computer, the file has code in it. I've uploaded the code to GitHub **[here](https://github.com/artyomkulimov/NebulaDevs_website)**. I can insert CSS code(copy and paste) into the empty file I see in DevTools and it updates the website, so I don't think it can be the linking.

**EDIT: I changed the code to proper formatting for the url_for, it didnt help, the static folder is still empty(i see the images, js, css in my editor but not with devtools and it doesnt show on my website)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your css file is not properly connected to the html file.

In your `index.html` file, You have did something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='../static/styles.css')}}">
```

Well, it's a wrong format to do so. You must do it like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static',filename='/styles.css')}}">
```

You don't need to write the `../static/` path because it's already done in `url_for('static'`. I hope you understood

Comment: hey, thanks for the response, ive tried this solution just now and I still have the same problem, FYI, its not just the CSS file, its the whole static folder that is 404(but i can see it in my editor).